# Adding a script & php to functions.php

Tags: plugins, php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, javascript

I usually work with javascript and never php.

My task is to add this script/php code to woocommerce.

```
<?php
$ImageUrl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' )[0];
$ItemId = $product->id;
$Title = $product-> get_title();
$ProductUrl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$CurrencySymbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
$Currency = get_woocommerce_currency();
$Price = $product->get_price();
$RegularPrice = $product->get_regular_price();
$DiscountAmount = $RegularPrice - $Price;
$terms = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
?>

<script>
 var Title = "<?php echo $Title; ?>";
 var ItemId = "<?php echo $ItemId; ?>";
 var ImageUrl = "<?php echo $ImageUrl; ?>";
 var ProductUrl = "<?php echo $ProductUrl; ?>";
 var CurrencySymbol = "<?php echo $CurrencySymbol; ?>";
 var Currency = "<?php echo $Currency; ?>";
 var Price = "<?php echo $Price; ?>";
 var DiscountAmount = "<?php echo $DiscountAmount; ?>";
 var RegularPrice = "<?php echo $RegularPrice; ?>";
 var _learnq = _learnq || [];

    _learnq.push(['track', 'Viewed Product', {
      Title: Title,
      ItemId: ItemId,
      ImageUrl: ImageUrl,
      Url: ProductUrl,
      Metadata: {
        Currency: Currency,
        CurrencySymbol: CurrencySymbol,
        Price: Price,
        DiscountAmount: DiscountAmount,
        RegularPrice: RegularPrice
      }
 }]);
 </script>
```

It can only be added to product pages.

Here is the solution I am trying:

```
/*
Add klaviyo script if the page is a product page
*/
if ( is_product() ) {
    function add_klaviyo_script() {
        echo '<?php
                $ImageUrl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), \'single-post-thumbnail\' )[0];
                $ItemId = $product->id;
                $Title = $product-> get_title();
                $ProductUrl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
                $CurrencySymbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
                $Currency = get_woocommerce_currency();
                $Price = $product->get_price();
                $RegularPrice = $product->get_regular_price();
                $DiscountAmount = $RegularPrice - $Price;
                $terms = get_terms( \'product_tag\' );
                ?>

                <script>
                var Title = "<?php echo $Title; ?>";
                var ItemId = "<?php echo $ItemId; ?>";
                var ImageUrl = "<?php echo $ImageUrl; ?>";
                var ProductUrl = "<?php echo $ProductUrl; ?>";
                var CurrencySymbol = "<?php echo $CurrencySymbol; ?>";
                var Currency = "<?php echo $Currency; ?>";
                var Price = "<?php echo $Price; ?>";
                var DiscountAmount = "<?php echo $DiscountAmount; ?>";
                var RegularPrice = "<?php echo $RegularPrice; ?>";
                var _learnq = _learnq || [];

                    _learnq.push([\'track\', \'Viewed Product\', {
                    Title: Title,
                    ItemId: ItemId,
                    ImageUrl: ImageUrl,
                    Url: ProductUrl,
                    Metadata: {
                        Currency: Currency,
                        CurrencySymbol: CurrencySymbol,
                        Price: Price,
                        DiscountAmount: DiscountAmount,
                        RegularPrice: RegularPrice
                    }
                }]);
                </script>';
    }
    /*
    Add klaviyo script to footer
    */
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_klaviyo_script' );
}
```

I am going to add this to the functions.php file.

My question is, is this the best approach for adding the php/script to the header? I have not worked with php or wordpress before so its very new to me. I thought about using wp_enque but I'm not sure if it will work given I have some php vars.

Answer (score 0):

First you should include this code in your footer.php - or similar.
Second:

```
if ( is_product() ) { //you are already in php
    function add_klaviyo_script() {
        echo '<?php // dont need to echo php
              $ItemId = $product->id;  // and variables
```

The solution(footer.php):

```
<footer>
   ...things
</footer>
<?php
if ( is_product() ) {
                $ImageUrl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), \'single-post-thumbnail\' )[0];
                $ItemId = $product->id;
                $Title = $product-> get_title();
                $ProductUrl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
                $CurrencySymbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
                $Currency = get_woocommerce_currency();
                $Price = $product->get_price();
                $RegularPrice = $product->get_regular_price();
                $DiscountAmount = $RegularPrice - $Price;
                $terms = get_terms( \'product_tag\' );
                ?>

                <script>
                var Title = "<?php echo $Title; ?>";
                var ItemId = "<?php echo $ItemId; ?>";
                var ImageUrl = "<?php echo $ImageUrl; ?>";
                var ProductUrl = "<?php echo $ProductUrl; ?>";
                var CurrencySymbol = "<?php echo $CurrencySymbol; ?>";
                var Currency = "<?php echo $Currency; ?>";
                var Price = "<?php echo $Price; ?>";
                var DiscountAmount = "<?php echo $DiscountAmount; ?>";
                var RegularPrice = "<?php echo $RegularPrice; ?>";
                var _learnq = _learnq || [];

                    _learnq.push([\'track\', \'Viewed Product\', {
                    Title: Title,
                    ItemId: ItemId,
                    ImageUrl: ImageUrl,
                    Url: ProductUrl,
                    Metadata: {
                        Currency: Currency,
                        CurrencySymbol: CurrencySymbol,
                        Price: Price,
                        DiscountAmount: DiscountAmount,
                        RegularPrice: RegularPrice
                    }
                }]);
                </script><?php
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually just ended up adding the snippet without the logic to the single product page. Thank you though!

Comment: That is viable too.